# Edge Slide slide vertices too

Tags: edges

I want to slide an edge but the vertices is also slips[image]
[image][image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like there is Z-fighting. Do you have one large face spanning the entire roof?

Comment: @nucleic550 what is Z-fighting? I have two faces from both side and then I loop cut into seven parts

Comment: You'll notice that the roof has a cloudy appearance, with parts that are light grey and parts that are dark grey. This is because there are two intersecting faces.
Regardless, are you trying to extrude the edge or simply move it?

Comment: @nucleic550 ah yes they are two different object. I want to move it

Answer (score 2):

It seems you're using Grab. With Grab (<kbd>g</kbd>) you're simply moving the edge, which is made out of vertices that it shares with the adjacent edges, hence they are also manipulated.

Try using Extrude (<kbd>e</kbd>) instead. This will create a new edge (a set of two vertices) in the exact same location that you can manipulate independent of the adjacent geometry.
If you then set the Transformation orientation to 'Local' , you can move it along the axis in the same direction as the original roof:

[image: quick mockup]